# iOS 9 supportedInterfaceOrientations not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIViewController` with the following code:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
     return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

I am not using a `UINavigationController`. When this `UIViewController` is being displayed, the device will still rotate to landscape. I am targeting iOS 9, what's the issue here?

Comment: did you try doing the same on xcode project settings ?

Comment: try disabling the lanscape left,right mode in xcode and only check portrait mode and see if it works!!!

Comment: I have other UIViewControllers that I want to allow rotation on. Just not this specific one. I have also made sure this UIViewController is set to the right class in my storyboard.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this in swift3?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So the issue was that I had defined the allowed orientations in `info.plist` which apparently overrides anything you do anywhere else throughout the project.

To correct the issue I removed the entries from `info.plist` and defined them in the project settings. Now everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks ! you saved my day. For the record, i've had this bug on ios 9.0, but it seems to be fixed on ios 9.1

Comment: Bryan,  I removed the entries from the info.plist file, but I don't understand what you mean by defining them in the project?  I still have all my VCs changing orientation.  Even if I added the methods to the VC to prevent it (supportedInterfaceOrientations, shouldAutoRotate, etc).  I'm trying to tackle allowing landscape mode chunk at a time, and need to prevent landscape mode for the VCs that need extensive refactoring.

Comment: Totally saved my day, thank you! Deleting the supported interface orientations in the Info.plist and then just implementing shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations fixed this for me.

Comment: Note that removing orientation support from info.plist will cause an error on upload (ITMS 90474) for iOS9 see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728711/xcode-7-error-itms-90474-invalid-bundle-cant-submit-to-apple

Comment: When you remove the orientations in `info.plist` it also changes the project settings.

Comment: @TicoBallagas  That's a red herring, because as your link shows, and the above answer already stated, setting 'Requires Full Screen' will fix any errors on upload.  What it will not to, and what everyone needs, is for the method to be called.  I have `shouldAutorotate` implemented in several view controllers, yet none of them get called.  XCode 8.2, iOS 10.2

Answer (score 25):

I don't think Bryan's answer works,for changing the orientations in project settings also changes the `info.plist` as @mrhangz commented.

If the issue is iOS9 only,it is probably due to the new feature of iOS9 in iPad called `Split view`.The iOS9 enable `Split view` by default in particular iPad device,see Apple documents [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015145-CH13-SW1).

[image]
The `split view` forced your app to support all orientations in all view once adoptted.So if you set all orientations support in either  `info.plist` or target general setting,and then `split view` is supported by default,which will ignore the orientation setting though `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in your viewController and support all orientations.

As the document written,if you checked `Requires full screen` in your target settings,then your app will not support `split view`.Now you can control orientations in code again.
[image]

Comment: This works for me. I needed this info, I do not know it.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I have `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate` in my view controller, but it never gets called, and I have 'Requires Full Screen' checked.  Always has been checked as far as I know.

Comment: Using Xcode 9 and testing on iPhoneX, I am seeing same issue. The overrides seem to have no effect and the suggestions about plist mods and requiring full screen do not effect the outcome in my testing.  The only things that seems to effect the outcome is locking down the rotations in the settings which applies app wide.

Wondering if anyone found the "secret" to getting this work, or it's still a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

I have try many solution, but the correct answer with working solution is:

ios 8 and 9, no need to edit info.plist.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
 return NO;
 }   



- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait |  UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
 }
```

[possible orientation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiinterfaceorientation?language=objc)

UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown

The orientation of the device cannot be determined.

UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait

The device is in portrait mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the bottom.

UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown

The device is in portrait mode but upside down, with the device held upright and the home button at the top.

UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft

The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the left side.

UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight

The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the right side.

Comment: You need to return UIInterfaceOrientationMask, not UIInterfaceOrientation to the supportedInterfaceOrientations (e.g. UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait)

Answer (score 0):

**In swift 5**

The code below will lock the current view controller into portrait mode but still allow the other view controllers to transition to landscape.  I do believe that you have to enable all the orientations at the project level and then turn then "off" using this method but am not sure if there is way to turn them back "on" one by one.

```
private var _orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    get { return self._orientations }
    set { self._orientations = .portrait }
}
```

A more thorough explanation of it all can be found here:
[The supportedInterfaceOrientations method doesn't override any method from its superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732948/the-supportedinterfaceorientations-method-doesnt-override-any-method-from-its-s/38732957)

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, for iPad, if *Supported interface orientations (iPad)* property in info.plist includes all the four orientations, with *UIRequiresFullScreen* property value as *NO*, iOS will treat your app as supporting split view. If an app supports split view feature, you can not disable it from rotating, at least by the ways above.

I have a detail answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785767/supportedinterfaceorientations-not-working/56267601#56267601).