# The supportedInterfaceOrientations method doesn't override any method from its superclass

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In a UIViewController, this code:

```
public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let mainController = self.mainViewController{
        return mainController.supportedInterfaceOrientations
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
}
```

gives the error `Method doesn't override any method from its superclass`

I am using Xcode 8 beta 4 and the iOS deployment target is 9.0, and `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` is set to No in the `Build Settings`

How could I convert the code above to Swift 3?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Like this:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
```

...and the rest as you have it.

#### The general pattern

A lot of Cocoa methods are properties now, so you implement them as override computed variables. So the pattern for moving from seed 3 (or earlier) to seed 4 is:

- Change `func` to `var`
- Delete `()`
- Change `->` to `:`

This works because a computed variable has a getter function, so the function you were implementing before simply turns into the getter function. And these are read-only properties, so you won't need a setter.

Similarly affected methods are `preferredStatusBarStyle`, `prefersStatusBarHidden`, `shouldAutorotate`, `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`, and many others. Look for `UIKIT_DEFINE_AS_PROPERTIES` in the Objective-C header.

#### Implications

In the longer term, there are other changes you can make. For example,  you *can* add a setter (dividing your implementation into `get` and `set` functions), and thus you can turn your implementation into a facade for a stored property. For example:

```
private var _orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    get { return self._orientations }
    set { self._orientations = newValue }
}
```

So now your code has a way to set this value. If you were returning different values at different times, this could make things a lot cleaner.

#### Further technical notes

Interestingly, this change has no direct effect on existing Objective-C code, because in Objective-C, the new property declaration, `@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIInterfaceOrientationMask supportedInterfaceOrientations;`, is satisfied by the same method as before:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

The reason is that in Objective-C, a `@property(readonly)` is merely a promise that a corresponding getter method exists, and that's exactly what this method is. But in Swift, the way to write an Objective-C property's getter method is through a *property*, that is, through an instance variable. So only Swift code is affected by the change: you have to rewrite your methods as properties.

Comment: You'll be doing this a lot, so get used to it now. :)

Comment: I added specific steps for turning a method override into a property override!

Comment: Awesome! Just waiting for the time required to accept your answer

Comment: Wait, there's more! Also added an explanation of why this change can be really cool.

Comment: @Aetherynne it's been almost one year i have no clue.

Comment: In iOS 9+ try this: 

[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;

Comment: how can call this from button click event