# How to force view controller orientation in iOS 10?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios10, uiinterfaceorientation

I have tried:

--> Subclassing UINavigationController and overriding autorotate methods

--> Overriding autorotate methods on MyViewController

--> And both.

Note: Also, I tried with autorotate sets NO and YES

This is my code:

NavigationControllerNoAutorotate:

```
@implementation NavigationControllerNoAutorotate

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

MyViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UINavigationController *)navigationController {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: The problem was that I was testing on iPad, and I activated the SplitView on deployment info. When "Requires Full Screen" is YES, split view is deactivated.

Comment: I found the solution on this link:[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782044/ios-9-supportedinterfaceorientations-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was testing on iPad, and I activated the SplitView on deployment info. When "Requires Full Screen" is YES, split view is deactivated.

I found the solution on this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782044/ios-9-supportedinterfaceorientations-not-working)