# Force one viewcontroller to be only landscape

Tags: ios, swift, landscape

In my swift project i have all my viewcontroller to only portrait and i want only 1 view controller to be only landscape

My settings [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DujS.png)

Answer (score 1):

To do this , you have to set the Settings for both portrait and landscape and all the following code in each view controller except in which you want a landscape view

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

For further help check  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651969/setting-device-orientation-in-swift-ios)

Comment: shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations are not fired :(

Comment: Check out this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535329/shouldautorotate-not-called-on-view-controller

Comment: I read post that i need to add extension of UINavigationController that override shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations, and it work for the first viewcontroller after navigation but others no